# Mismatch Likes data in Instagram API

Tags: instagram-api

I'm trying to get all likes from a post on Instagram via their API, but it returns only 118 likes data instead of 136. Are there any limitations on this? Kindly help me to resolve this. 
P.S : I am using live app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is limit of 120 likes and 150 comments via API, the actual count returned in API response is normal to be slightly less than the limit value